# T-SQL order of identity generation for INSERT with multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL (SQL Server 2017), I have a table variable defined similar to this (field names changed for sample):

```
DECLARE @people TABLE (
    PersonID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Age INT
)
```

If I insert multiple rows using a single insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO @people (Name, Age)
VALUES
    ('Mike', 42),
    ('Sue', 24),
    ('Brad', 33)
```

Is the order of the identity column guaranteed to be the same as the order I listed the rows in the VALUES part of the INSERT?  Namely, can I be sure that Mike will be 1, Sue 2, and Brad 3?  Or is it unspecified and I might get different orders different times?

Comment: If you make it a `PRIMARY KEY`, yes.  Otherwise, you will have to try it.

Comment: I can't find it guaranteed from a quick Google. Is there any reason you are using an `IDENTITY` here? If you need specific values such as `Mike` getting a `PersonID` of `1` can you just create it as non identity and insert the desired values for that column explicitly along with the other columns?

Comment: @MartinSmith In my real scenario, the table variable holds a list of types of costs, some of which are well-known that I want to preload and use their IDs almost like an enum, but others will be dynamically created so an identity column would make generating IDs for those much easier.  I can think of a few other ways to handle the situation, but all of them are more verbose or more complicated.

Comment: You can use the approach in the dupe of using  a table valued constructor and adding an ancillary column for use with `order by` to get something guaranteed to allocate the identity values in that order

Comment: Or just do singleton inserts!

Comment: I will die on this hill - if you have a column whose values you care about, the identity property is not appropriate. More gently, in your mixed-use scenario where you want only *some* of the rows to have well-known values, just do `set identity_insert on` and again explicitly specify the values.

Comment: @BenThul - you can't with a table variable

Comment: Then don't use a table variable?

Comment: I'm gonna die on @BenThul's hill too. Sometimes i use another column if i want to keep some specific IDs umm, specific